# Flattening hierarchical data with Linq in VB.NET

Tags: linq

Given the following structure:

```
Public Class Vendor
    Public Property Accounts As Account()
End Class

Public Class Account
    Public Property Services As Service()
End Class

Public Class Service
    Public Property Name As String
End Class
```

How do I get a flat list of all included Services in all accounts given a single Vendor? This is what I've tried so far:

```
vendor.Accounts.Select(Function(acct) acct.Services) 'Returns a collection of services collections
```

I know I'm just missing an obvious operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for SelectMany.

```
vendor.Accounts.SelectMany(Function(acct) acct.Services)
```

And if you want only the unique ones, slap a .Distinct() on the end.